# How to ensure the Mist GUI client is running on the new, hard-forked blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, hardforks

I installed a while ago *geth* **1.4.17** from the git repo (together with *cpp-ethereum*, the *genoil CUDA miner*, and the *Mist* GUI wallet). However, now I can't figure for the life of me how to upgrade geth to *1.5.x* (in preparation for the impending hard-fork), so I just downloaded the latest version of Mist (0.8.7), and it's syncing to the blockchain just fine. How can I ensure that it *will* be running on the new, hard-forked chain, though?

Comment: How did you install geth and mist? Just re-do it the same way and you are fine.

Comment: @5chdn I forgot how I got it to compile and now the Makefiles are not working for me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the **latest version of Mist, just restart it**.

Alex from Mist [said:](https://twitter.com/avsa/status/800822730178248706)

> If you launch Mist now, it should auto-update to Geth 1.5.2. If you
>   have it running, we suggest you restart the app before the fork.

He explained more [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5e6wrw/uavsa_on_twitter_if_you_launch_mist_now_it_should/daaajoq).